# Facetime audio takes up SSD space

Tags: iphone, audio, ssd, memory, facetime

I was just using FaceTime audio and my phone told me I was running out of space.  I was curious as to how this was possible as I knew I have about 2GB free yesterday.  I kept going back in and checking space whilst on the call and it eventually got down to 0 bytes free.  Once the call was over, it went back up to 2.4GB.

Given that RAM and SSD space aren't wildly different things, it seems possible that FaceTime would overflow it's RAM usage onto the SSD.

Does anyone know if what I'm observing is true? Is FaceTime really using many gigabytes of my iPhone's storage when its operating? If this is true, why is FaceTime buffering so much to disk like this? And is the buffered content encrypted in anyway?

Comment: Have you used an app such as DaisyDisk to monitor your free space and identify areas where you could free up some storage?

Comment: @PatrickMcMahon it's an iPhone, not a Mac. Daisy Disk isn't an option.

Comment: The question is more about FaceTime Audio taking up additional space when I make a call, rather than where else I could save space.

Comment: Does FaceTime tell you how much space it's taking up in Usage settings? As in, did you actually see FaceTime's reported used storage increasing?

Comment: @user24601 - The space frees up as soon as the call finishes.  I'll check again the next time I make a long call to see if it appears under FaceTime specifically.  But that's the only thing I'm doing and as it clears up as soon as the call finishes, seems pretty unlikely that it's anything else...

Comment: It could be cache. When I am clearing up cache junk with Battery Doctor, my iPad says I have no space left.